# VB.net get the first word after a specified string

Tags: vb.net, string, split, substring

I need to get the **first word only, after a specified string** like so (pseudo):

```
my_string = "Hello Mr. John, how are you today?"
my_search_string = "are"
result = "you"
```

I tried to do it by using the following approach but i get the rest of the string after my "key" string and not a single word.

```
    Dim search_string As String = "key"
    Dim x As Integer = InStr(Textbox1.text, search_string)

    Dim word_after_key As String = Textbox1.text.Substring(x + search_string.Length - 1)
```

Comment: Psst: use `String.IndexOf` instead of `InStr`.

Comment: You need to look for the next word boundary after the index you found. This can either be a space, any kind of punctuation or whatever you define it to be.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Dim str = "Hello Mr. John, how are you today?"
Dim key = " are "
Dim i = str.IndexOf(key)
If i <> -1 Then
    i += key.Length
    Dim j = str.IndexOf(" ", i)
    If j <> -1 Then
        Dim result = str.Substring(i, j - i)
    End If
End If
```

Or this perhaps:

```
Dim str = "Hello Mr. John, how are you today?"
Dim key = "are"
Dim words = str.Split(" "C)
Dim i = Array.IndexOf(words, key)
If i <> -1 AndAlso i <> words.Length - 1 Then
    Dim result = words(i + 1)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This works too.

```
Dim my_string as String = "Hello Mr. John, how are you today?"
Dim SearchString As String = "are"
Dim StartP As Integer = InStr(my_string, SearchString) + Len(SearchString) + 1 
' to account for the space

If StartP > 0 Then
    Dim EndP As Integer = InStr(StartP, my_string, " ")
    MsgBox(Mid(my_string, StartP, EndP - StartP))
End If
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    Dim sa As String
    Dim s As String
    Dim sp() As String
    sa = TextBox1.Text 'this text box contains value **Open Ended Schemes(Debt Scheme - Banking and PSU Fund)**
    sp = sa.Split("(") 'Here u get the output as **Debt Scheme - Banking and PSU Fund)** which means content after the open bracket...
    sp = sp(1).Split(")") 'Here u get the output as Debt Scheme - Banking and PSU Fund which means content till the close bracket...
    s = Split(sp(0))(0) 'Here it will take the first word, which means u will get the output as **Debt**
    s = Split(sp(0))(1) 'Change the index as per the word u want, here u get the output as **Scheme**
```

Comment: This answer may be right and provide a solution to the question. but you may add the explanation of how it solves the problem so the future reader can get the idea of how it works.

Comment: I'm getting `s` returned as "**Open**" when I run this.  Did I miss something?

Comment: u can remove the bracket infront of the word open... because s wil return the content after the bracket...